# Trying to use SOH as delimiter for postgres table import from AWS S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, import, delimiter

Question: Is there a way to get AWS S3 import to Postres to work with a delimiter that requires escapes?

I have table data in a delimited format. It's stored in Amazon (AWS) S3. The delimiter is SOH (ASCII 001) since our data analysts have found that it's not used in the table data.

I'm trying to import these delimited files into Postgres (Amazon RDS) using the AWS postgres extension library aws_s3.

The form of the import statement is as follows:

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 (
  'path_type_attribution_summary',
  'path_creation_method, method, path_type, path_interaction_index, interaction_attrib_share, path_interaction',
  'DELIMITER ''|''',
  aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
    'ci-360-datahub-data-dev-us-east-1',
    'test_chdole/test2/path_type_attribution_summary/path_type_attribution_summary',
    'us-east-1')
);
```

That example uses the vertical bar delimiter (single character). In order to get SOH in there, I need to use some kind of escape. Something like:

```
  'DELIMITER ''\001''',
```

I have tried a variety of approaches. I get the same error every time:

```
ERROR:  COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "copy path_type_attribution_summary (path_creation_method, method, path_type, path_interaction_index, interaction_attrib_share, path_interaction) from '/rdsdbdata/extensions/aws_s3/amazon-s3-fifo-32165-20210115T161944Z-0' with DELIMITER '\001'"
SQL function "table_import_from_s3" statement 1
SQL state: 0A000
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with Postgres or the aws_s3 library.

Has anyone gotten something like this to work?

Answer (score 0):

As the delimiter SOH = ASCII code 001 is a non-printable character. You have to use a Extended String Syntax i.e,

```
DELIMITER E'\001'
```

For more information [click here](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/LoadingUTF-8FormatData.htm)